# Cannot get docker to clone private git repos

Tags: git, docker, ssh, cloudant, ibm-cloud-private

I have a docker image residing on IBM private cloud container registry. From there, it's being fetched and built remotely to be deployed on a Kubernetes cluster. Security is not an issue on that registry so currently we are passing our SSH keys as variables. My current Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ARG SECRET_KEY="***"
ARG PUB_KEY="***"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common git ssh-client
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-setuptools
RUN easy_install3 pip

RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
RUN echo "${SECRET_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo "${PUB_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN ssh-keyscan git.ng.bluemix.net >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chmod 644 /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN chmod 755 /root/.ssh

RUN echo "IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

RUN bash ./build.sh
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "-u", "updater.py"]
```

build.sh is a bash script which clones a few private git repos. With this code, I'm receiving the following error

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

i looked up solutions and they involved using ssh-agent. Using `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` I get `Agent pid 8`

However, when I include `ssh-add -l` or other commands, I receive
 `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

**EDIT:** Based on a different SO question, I changed a couple lines in my Dockerfile to have

```
RUN eval `ssh-agent s` && \
    ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    bash ./build.sh
```

as I read that ssh-agent is killed by the time ssh-add is called. However, with this, I receive `Enter passphrase for /root/.ssh/id_rsa` when the key is an unencrypted key.

Comment: You could generate a passphrase-free key just for use by this Docker image.

Comment: This is a passphrase-free key.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent hours fixing this and turns out while my edited code above was needed, the main issue wasn't with ssh-agent or anything else. I was passing my Private key as a default variable in the dockerfile so I backspaced all the new-lines.

Turns out, **new lines in the private key are important**

Adding a bunch of `\n` to create newlines in the private key worked